# Error en React: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy comenzando a usar React en mis proyectos y todavía no entiendo el funcionamiento al renderizar React child que es el error que estoy teniendo.
Tengo un componente que usa cards para renderizar productos desde una API pero al intentar renderizar cada producto me da el error

> 'Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, description, url}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.'

Mi componente que contiene las cards es el siguiente:

```
export function Recommends() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1); 
  const itemsPerPage = 10; 

  async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8090/products");
    const data = await response.json();
    setData(data);
  }
  console.log("Data:", data);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  
  const shuffledData = shuffle(data);
  
  const getItemsForPage = (page) => {
    const startIndex = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage;
    const endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerPage;
    return shuffledData.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
  };

  
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage);

  const handlePageChange = (selectedPage) => {
    setCurrentPage(selectedPage.selected);
  };

  
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Recomendaciones</h3>
      
      
      {data.length > 0 ? (
        <div className="grid-container">
          {getItemsForPage(currentPage).map((item) => (
            <ProductCard
              key={item.id}
              img_src={item.images.url}
              titulo={item.name}
              descripcion={item.description}
              precio={item.price}
              categoria={item.category}
              id={item.id}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>No data available</p>
      )}

      <ReactPaginate
        previousLabel={"Anterior"}
        nextLabel={"Siguiente"}
        breakLabel={"..."}
        breakClassName={"break-me"}
        pageCount={totalPages}
        marginPagesDisplayed={2}
        pageRangeDisplayed={5}
        onPageChange={handlePageChange}
        containerClassName={"pagination"}
        subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
        activeClassName={"active"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Y mi ProductCard:

```
export function ProductCard({
  img_src,
  titulo,
  descripcion,
  precio,
  categoria,
  id,
}) {
  return (
    <div className="prod_card">
      {/* <div>
        <img className="img_prod" src={img_src} alt={titulo} />
      </div> */}
      {img_src && img_src.map((url, index) => (
        <img key={index} src={url} alt={`${titulo}-img-${index}`} />
      ))}
      <div className="prod_detail">
        <h3>{titulo}</h3>
        <p>{descripcion}</p>
        <p>Categoría: {categoria}</p>
        <p className="precio">Precio de alquiler: {precio}</p>
        <Link to={`/producto/${id}`}>
          <button>Ver mas</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Intentos

- He visto preguntas similares pero ninguna exactamente igual.
- Ya he realizado las recomendaciones que se encuentran en internet
  (incluso ChatGPT) sobre este error pero no me ha servido, si alguien
  puede sugerirme algo nuevo estaría muy agradecida.

Comment: veo que el campo name no existe en product card, crees que eso esté relacionado?

Comment: Ruslan el name se lo paso a la prop titulo

Comment: entonces cual es la salida de tu ` console.log("Data:", data);`? si trae todos los campos como `price` ?